# что делать если в команде dotnet new нет шаблонов

Tags: c#, .net

у меня нету шаблона wpf при запуске команды dotnet new wpf. что делать?

Comment: можно попробовать ```dotnet new wpf --install``` для <=6.0 / ```dotnet new install wpf``` для >=7.0, если он просто не установлен

Comment: Пробовал не работает

Answer (score 0):

Какая у вас версия .Net? Если старая, то wpf не будет поддерживаться. Установите новую версию .Net и попробуйте заново создать.